# What does the symbol := mean in mathematics?

Tags: notation

What does the symbol := mean in mathematics?
for example, C(continuum) := |R|

Comment: It usually means that this is a definition, not a proven/provable statement or an equation where you are trying to solve something.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh, thank you verymuch!

Comment: I could have sworn someone has asked this question before recently. I just can't find it right now. If someone can find where the duplicate is, that would be helpful.

Comment: @KingDuken, do you mean this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838678/confused-about-notation-versus-plain-old

Comment: Thanks @ZainPatel. That first link is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 6):

It means it is a definition in most contexts.

$f(x):=x^2-\sin 2x + \pi$
means I define $f(x)$ by the expression on the other side.

However, in most contexts, it is a superfluous notation as you argue around it.

Comment: While I agree that it isn't necessary most of the time, I'd still encourage its use, because it provides some additional help to the reader. (E.g. in fine structure theory there is a huge amount of notation floating around and I welcome any kind of help to keep track of all of it - especially during talks.)